# Can one synchronized method access another synchronized method in C#?

Tags: c#, synchronization, deadlock

Suppose I have the two following methods:

```
Object sync = new Object();
…
public void method1() { lock(sync) { … } }
public void method2() { lock(sync) { method1() … }}
```

My question here is would this cause any deadlock? Looks like method2 is trying to obtain lock sync when it is already holding it.

Comment: What happens when you try it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: While normally a good advise, with Multitasking you **really** need to know what you are doing. Not doing that get's you into race conditons.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't cause any deadlocks. `lock` statement is converted into  `System.Threading.Monitor` `Enter` and `Exit` calls. [Documentation says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.enter?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> It is legal for the same thread to invoke Enter more than once without it blocking; however, an equal number of Exit calls must be invoked before other threads waiting on the object will unblock.

You call `lock` both times from the same thread, so deadlock won't occur.

Comment: That being said, it is generally a bad Idea to share a mutex object, unless those opeartions are truly mutualyl exclusive (like a add and remove operation on a ConcurrentList). You use a dedicated, private object **because** there is no way some other code could even try to lock it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This would not cause a deadlock as the call from method2 to method1 would be on the same thread. Lock only syncronises calls across threads, not on the same thread. 
See the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) for more info.